# Puntero a la k-ésima celda dentro de lista

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Me dan un natural k > 0, y tengo que retornar un puntero a la k-ésima celda de una lista dada.

Si la k-ésima celda no existe retorna nil.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
   function largo(l : ListaSumables): integer;

 var
    contador: integer;
    p: ListaSumables;

begin
 contador:= 0;
 p:= l;
 while p <> nil do
  begin
   contador:= contador + 1;
   p:= p^.siguiente;    (* avanzar a la siguiente celda *)
 end;

 largo:= contador;
end;

var 
 i, j, t   : Natural;
 p        : ListaSumables;

begin
 new(p);
 p := nil;

 i:=1;
while i <= MAXTablero*MAXTablero do
begin

{ Lista Vacia } 
if lista = nil then
 begin
  new(p);
  p^.siguiente := nil;
  p := lista
 end;

 { Primer elemento }
 if k = 0 then
  begin
  new(p);
  p := lista;
 end;

 if (k > 0) and (k < largo(lista)) then
  begin
   new(p);
   p := lista^.siguiente;
 end; 

 inc(i);
 end;
end;
```

¿Cómo haría para avanzar una posición en la lista e imprimir esa celda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás cometiendo varios errores.

1. Realmente no hace falta saber el largo de la lista, y si hiciera falta, podrías almacenar el valor en una variable para no recorrerla en cada iteración del ciclo.
2. Reservas memoria para nuevos elementos dentro de la rutina (llamadas a `new`, esto tampoco hace falta. Con listas, la convención es que vas a retornar un puntero al k-esimo elemento de la lista, no a un elemento nuevo.

Así, una función para retornar el k-esimo elemento de una lista, luciría algo así como:

```
function ObtenerCeldaPosicion(K: Natural; ALista: TListaSumables): TListaSumables;
var 
  PosicionActual: Natural;
begin
  if K <= 0 then 
    Result := nil
  else
  begin
    Result := ALista;
    PosicionActual := 1;
    while (PosicionActual < K) and (Result <> nil) do
    begin
      Inc(PosicionActual);
      Result := Result^.Siguiente;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

En el asumimos varias cosas:

1. Natural es un tipo de dato entero (Integer, Int64, SmallInt, etc).
2. TListaSumables es un puntero a un registro

Aunque quizás a primera vista no lo parezca, el algoritmo cubre *casos especiales* y tiene las siguientes características:

1. Lista vacía, el parámetro ALista es nil. La función retornará nil, ya que el K-esimo elemento no existe
2. Si la lista se agota (tiene menos que K elementos), también retornará nil
3. La lista se recorre una sola vez.
4. El primer elemento de la lista es el 1, no el 0. Una lista no es un arreglo, considero que no tiene sentido tener una lista cuyo primer elemento se considere el 0 elemento. Lo natural es que el K-esimo elemento de una lista sea el elemento cuya posición es la K. Si necesitas (como muestra tu ejemplo final) que el primer elemento de la lista sea considerado el 0, adaptar el algoritmo te queda como ejercicio. (Si lo comprendes no será difícil).

Comment: `Result` es una variable de `TListaSumable` declarada en var?

Comment: @ro2: No, y no hace falta declararla. `Result` es una variable implícita que existe en todas las funciones. Si bien no es parte de la especificación original, es una _mejora_ introducida al lenguaje `Pascal` por Borland en Delphi 1 (en 1995) y adoptada por prácticamente todos los compiladores moderno del lenguaje. `Result` tiene el mismo tipo de la función y asignar un valor a dicha variable es equivalente a asignar dicho valor a la función en si (es decir, al resultado de la función).

Comment: No tengo reputacion, pero tu modelo me sirvió, lo modifique a mis necesidades y a lo que me pedía el ejercicio.

Comment: me alegra que te fuera de utilidad @ro2, no hace falta que tengas reputación para [aceptar una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) a tu propia pregunta, si te ha sido útil, ni para [votar por ella](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: @jachguate Para votar me parece que si que hay un mínimo de 15 de rep. Al menos en SOen creo que estaba así.